# @ForeignCollectionField of a Database Class using ORMLITE is null whenever that table queried

Tags: android, sql, database, ormlite

This is the DB table

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Menus")
public class Menus {

@DatabaseField(columnName = "menuId", id = true)
private String id;

@ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
private ForeignCollection<Test> test;}
```

This is the foreign collection

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Test")
public class Test  {
@DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoCreate = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
private Menus menu;

@DatabaseField(columnName = "id", id = true)
private String id;

@DatabaseField(columnName = "name")
private String name;}
```

I queried

```
    ArrayList<Menus> courseList = null;
    try {
        courseList = (ArrayList<Menus>) menuDao.queryForAll();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get every terms except the foreignCollection which is returned null.

Does anybody has a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I know you have the foreignAutoRefresh set to true, but have you tried calling

```
menuDao.refresh(test.getMenu());
```

? 
I have had some problems with the foreignAutoRefresh as well as the "eager"ness of the ForeignCollectionFields but if you manually refresh it will work every time.